# Help with this geometrical approach to deriving the lens equation for weak lensing

Tags: geometry, gravitational-lensing, weak-lensing

All images and quotations are from Schneider, Kochanek and Wambsganss.

[image]

Here is an image of a typical weak lensing setup. Since $D_{ds}$ and $D_s$ are much larger than the extent of the lens and source plane, we can model the curvature of the light ray as a kink at the point of the lens.

$\hat{\alpha}$ is the deflection angle.

$\eta$ is the 2d position of the source on a source plane.

$\xi$ is the ray impact parameter.

Small angle approximations apply to the deflection angle.

> From the figure we can read off the geometric condition that $$\vec{\eta}=\frac{D_s}{D_d}\vec{\xi}-D_{ds}\vec{\hat{\alpha}}(\vec{\xi}).$$

I am struggling to understand where this has come from geometrically. Could someone please explain?

For completeness I will include the rest of the derivation in case it aids any explanations. We introduce angular coordinates by $$\vec{\eta}=D_s\vec{\beta}$$ and $$\vec{\xi}=D_d\vec{\theta}.$$ Now we transform the first equation to $$\vec{\beta}=\vec{\theta}-\frac{D_{ds}}{D_s}\vec{\hat{\alpha}}(D_d\vec{\theta})=\vec{\theta}-\vec{\alpha}(\vec{\theta}).$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Took me a while, but i think I figured it out.[image]

Lets use a distance $\Gamma$. In first order approx $\Gamma=\theta*D_s$ and $\eta=\Gamma-\alpha*D_{ds}$. So that:

$\Gamma=\theta*D_s=\eta+\alpha*D_{ds}$

And as $\theta=\xi/D_s$

$\eta=\theta*D_s-\alpha*D_{ds}=\frac{\xi}{D_d}D_s+\alpha D_{ds}$

Giving the previous relation. I am sure maybe there is a way to prove this without considering $\Gamma$ but it explains the relation.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is where it comes from?

[image]

Triangles $ACB$ and $ECF$ are similar so

$\dfrac {\xi}{D_d} = \dfrac {AB}{D_s} \Rightarrow AB = \dfrac {D_s}{D_d} \xi = \eta + AG$

For small angles $AG \approx \alpha D_{ds}$ and the result follows